# Jquery link in html output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why is this not possible?

```
$(function() { 
    $('.link').on('click', function(e) {
    alert('Works');
    });     
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#link').html('<a href="#" class="link">Link</a>');
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="link"></div>
```

It works if i delete the DIV and manually write the HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
```

Comment: Try `$('#link').on('click', '.link', function() { alert('fdsa'); });`. Let me know if this works

Comment: on click is not binding in your case just use .bind() then it works fine

Comment: Both things works. Thanks guys ;)